# Internet slows to a halt on one computer when another connects with ethernet - otherwise works fine

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, internet-connection

I've recently moved in with my partner and found that whenever his computer is on my internet connection slows down to the extent that I can't load webpages, but the moment his is turned off mine works perfectly.

It isn't affected by other devices connected wirelessly (we all have phones and laptops connected most of the time), and if I connect my laptop via ethernet, same lead same port, it doesn't have the same problem, so seems to just be something with my computer.

We're both on Windows 7, my network adapter is `Intel(R) Ethernet connection I217-V` and I'm using `firefox`. Where I was living before, I was using the same computer and connected with two others all via ethernet and we didn't have any problems. I've tried a few things below but no joy so far:

- checked for viruses with AVG - nothing comes up - and also tried using ComboFix after seeing it suggested as a more intensive tool but again no effect
- different ethernet cable and switching us around in the ports
- reinstalled the driver for my ethernet adapter and tried going back to an earlier version
- Changed the link speed settings to 1.0Gbps Full Duplex, then 100 Mbps Full Duplex and then back to Auto Negotiation. Also been through the diagnostics for the adapter cable and hardware on this tab and all seems fine
- Changed Gigabit Master Slave Mode to Force Master Mode but no change so then back again to Auto Detect
- Had a look for programs like AMD quickstream that I heard others had problems with but haven't found anything
- Reset TCP/IP

Comment: Try accessing your router (or modem if you have an all in one device) and check if there are any settings to do with Qos (quality of service). Qos is used to determine which packets are sent first by the device. Unfortunately I can't give you any more specific instructions since it varies so much by device, if it's there at all. Otherwise I would suggest trying a different router.

Comment: @Curtis Thanks for your response. We've just had a look and it's a Virgin Superhub 3.11 but, on logging in, it doesn't look like it has any settings to do with Qos unfortunately. I'll see if we can get hold of a different router - it just seems odd that the problem only affects my pc.